# Evaluate $f = x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3x_4$ only via $\oplus$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Evaluate $f = x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3x_4$ only via $\oplus$

$x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3x_4 = (x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_1x_2) \lor x_3x_4 = (x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_1x_2) \oplus x_3x_4 \oplus (x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_1x_2)x_3x_4$

How can one get rid of the conjunction?

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say 'evaluate .. via $\oplus$', do you mean that you have to find an equivalent expression using only $\oplus$?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Well, unfortunately that is impossible: if you have an expression built up from $\oplus$'s alone and put it on a truth-ttable, then it will always be true in exactly an even number of cases ... but your original expression will be true in $13$ of the $16$ rows.